# Reconnect to a websocket server if a condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I want to stream real-time data of the order book of `BTC/USD` using a WebSocket connection to the FTX Exchange. After the first snapshot of the order book, the WebSocket returns updates that I apply to my local reconstructed order book. To ensure that my order book is synchronized, I have to check a crc32 integer after every update. If this number matches the checksum in the message, I can be confident that my order book is well synchronized. However, sometimes the checksum is not right, and I need to reset the connection, i.e. unsubscribe to the channel and subscribe right after.
At the end of the `on_message`function, I check if the checksum is successful. If it is not, I close the connection but I would like to clear the memory  (i.e. the global objects `asks, bids, checksum`) and reconnect right after. How can I do it?

Should I just add a `while True` loop at the end? Like this one?

```
while True:
    ws.run_forever()
```

I don't like this `while True`solution because it's impossible for me to stop it, I have to quit the terminal.

My code is the following

```
import websocket,json
import zlib
from decimal import Decimal
import binascii
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
from typing import Iterable, Sequence

asks = {}
bids = {}
checksum = {'checksum':0}
def format_e(dec):
    return ('{:.' + str(len(dec.as_tuple().digits) - 1) + 'e}').format(dec)

def check_sum(
    asks: Iterable[Sequence[float]], bids: Iterable[Sequence[float]]
) -> int:
    asks=[[level[0],level[1]]for level in asks.items()]
    bids=[[level[0],level[1]]for level in bids.items()]

    order_book_hash_iterator = zip_longest(bids, asks, fillvalue=tuple())
    check_string = ":".join(
        (
            str(token)
            for ask_level, bid_level in order_book_hash_iterator
            for token in chain(ask_level, bid_level)
        )
    )

    return binascii.crc32(check_string.encode("ascii"))
    
    
def on_open(ws):
    print('Opened connection')
    asks.clear()
    bids.clear()
    subscribe_message = {'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'orderbook','market':'BTC/USD'}
    ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe_message))


def on_message(ws,message):
    js=json.loads(message)
    if js['type'] == 'partial':
        print('Get Snapshot')
        for level in js['data']['asks']:
            asks[level[0]]=level[1]
        for level in js['data']['bids']:
            bids[level[0]]=level[1]
        checksum['checksum']=js['data']['checksum']
    if js['type'] == 'update':
        for level in js['data']['asks']:
            if level[1]==0:
                asks.pop(level[0])
            else:
                asks[level[0]]=level[1]
        for level in js['data']['bids']:
            if level[1]==0:
                bids.pop(level[0])
            else:
                bids[level[0]]=level[1]
    if check_sum(asks,bids) != js['data']['checksum']:
        print('Error')
        ws.close()


socket = "wss://ftx.com/ws/"
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket,on_open=on_open)
ws.on_message = lambda ws,msg: on_message(ws,msg)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: If the websocket alway returned a valid value (hypothetically), wouldn't your script run forever as well (due to `ws.run_forever()`) and wouldn't you have to terminate it by quitting the terminal as well? Or do you have some other mechanism to stop the websocket app in that case?

Comment: @Grismar the problem is that the websocket returns a snapshot of the orderbook at the subscription and from the second message it starts sending updates. When the checksum is incorrect, I need to acquire a new snapshot and the only way I see to do it is to unsubscribe and subscribe again

Comment: I appreciate that @apt45, but I was asking because you point out reasons not to want to use `while True:`. Is your question ultimately "how to make my application interruptable?" (and do you need that answer for `run_forever()` itself as well?) Or is the question whether resubscribing is the correct approach? Or ...?

Comment: @Grismar thanks for being patient with me. While I can stop `run_forever()`just by (Cmd)+., if I put a while True loop I literally have to quit the Terminal to make the script stop working

Comment: @Grismar I mean a `KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: Thanks, it's clear that you meant a `KeyboardInterrupt` - there would be a way to get your `while` loop to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` as well. However, after running your code, I'm noticing that the response doesn't include `js['data']['checksum']` and as a result fails with several exceptions, ending in an error. Is the code you shared the code you're actually using? Specifically, your code seems to initiate subscription, but not actual retrieval of any data? And your `on_message` does not deal with the `subscribed` message?

Comment: @Grismar yes, the code is the same. I am running it in a clean session and I do receive the js['data']['checksum'] data.

Comment: @Grismar Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248273/discussion-between-apt45-and-grismar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
# everything up to and including `on_open` the same


class ChecksumException(Exception):
    pass


def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)
    js = json.loads(message)
    if js['type'] == 'partial':
        print('Get Snapshot')
        for level in js['data']['asks']:
            asks[level[0]] = level[1]
        for level in js['data']['bids']:
            bids[level[0]] = level[1]
        checksum['checksum'] = js['data']['checksum']
    if js['type'] == 'update':
        for level in js['data']['asks']:
            if level[1] == 0:
                asks.pop(level[0])
            else:
                asks[level[0]] = level[1]
        for level in js['data']['bids']:
            if level[1] == 0:
                bids.pop(level[0])
            else:
                bids[level[0]] = level[1]
    if js['type'] == 'subscribed':
        return
    # so, checking this for *any* type of message, except 'subscribed'
    if check_sum(asks, bids) != js['data']['checksum']:
        raise ChecksumException


def main():
    socket = "wss://ftx.com/ws/"
    while True:
        ws = None
        try:
            ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open)
            ws.on_message = lambda w=ws, msg=None: on_message(w, msg)
            print('Connecting...')
            ws.run_forever()
            print('Keyboard interrupt, stopping')
            break
        except ChecksumException:
            ws.close()
            print('Checksum error, closed')
            # no break here, so the loop continues and will reconnect


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're welcome - note that after the keyboard interrupt, `ws` is not formally closed, since I assumed the `WebSocketApp` does so itself (as it appears to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception itself). However, if you want to be safe, you could add a `ws.close()` before the break of course, or better yet, add it in a `finally` so that it always happens, even if other exceptions arise.